# upload excel file using ASP.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

How to upload excel file using ASP.net and C#?

Comment: Upload to where? Be spesific.

Comment: What have you tried? A quick search reveals lots of information http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=upload+excel+file+asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your aspx page you can use the following...make sure you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag it will allow the posting of files.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="excel-file" name="excel-file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Getting the file from the form post...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.IsPostback)
    {
        var yourFile = this.Request.Files["excel-file"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Would not be very easy it is ?

```
<!-- front end -->
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Excel File" 
            onclick="btnUpload_Click" />

//backend
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xls" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xlsx")
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/temp/Forecast.xls"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [This](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-Sheet-into-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net.aspx)
It works perfectly, without anything needed to be changed in the code.